# Self host url. What is the difference between * and +?

Tags: c#, owin, self-hosting

I have been looking at examples of self hosted web api and wcf services.

I have been noticing the url that these endpoints bind to use two distinct url's and I did not know what the difference between the two url formations.

The two types of endpoint url's are

```
http://*:8080
http://+:8080
```

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between these two url's in a self hosted environment?